# How to write RegExp for Dynamically Change product Id and anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

I want to extract all products url from regexp from `anchor tag <a>`

each product has `id` in anchor tag and which changes only some letters.

As you can see `<a id="ctl00_cphMain_rPdctG_.*"` here id is static upto `ctl00_cphMain_rPdctG_` for all products, After that it changes to `ctl01_hTitle` , `ctl02_hTitle` like that.

below is my code

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("website url here");


    preg_match_all(
        '/<div class=\"pdct\-inf\">(.*?)<\/div>/s',
        $html,
        $posts    
    );

    print_r($posts). "\n";

    foreach ($posts as $posts) {

    $str = $posts[1][0];

    preg_match('/<a id="ctl00_cphMain_rPdctG_.*" href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>/m',$str,$match);

    print_r($match) . "\n"; 
    print($match[2]) . "\n";

    }
```

As now this provide output for all products and array for only one first product.

I want to apply for loop for that which fetch data for all products and I can store that in php variable to export in csv..

Need some correction in for loop.

Current Ouput -

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a id="ctl00_cphMain_rPdctG_ctl01_hTitle" href="/whirlpool-whirlpool-direct-drive-285753a-ap3963893.html">Whirlpool Direct Drive Washer Mot...</a>
    [1] => /whirlpool-whirlpool-direct-drive-285753a-ap3963893.html
    [2] => Whirlpool Direct Drive Washer Mot...
)

Whirlpool Direct Drive Washer Mot...
```

**expected output for all products**

so `$match[1]` stores url and `$match[2]` variable store name of product.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

---

**Edit**

How can I add for loop which changes value for `$posts[1][0]`

Code without For Loop -

```
<?php 

$html = file_get_contents("Website url here ");


preg_match_all(
    '/<div class=\"pdct\-inf\">(.*?)<\/div>/s',
    $html,
    $posts    
);
//echo "First row posts\n";
print_r($posts). "\n";

$str = $posts[1][0];


preg_match('/<a id="ctl00_cphMain_rPdctG_.*" href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>/m',$str,$match);

echo "Second row match\n";
print_r($match) . "\n"; 

echo "Third  value \n";
print($match[2]) . "\n";
```

Comment: Your question is cant understand. Now you got result this only $match[1] stores url and $match[2] variable store name of product.

Comment: yes it works for only one product. I need to be work for all products which return anchor url and text within tag

Comment: ok other product id is like this ? id="ctl01_cphMain_rPdctG_.*", id="ctl02_cphMain_rPdctG_.*",..,

Comment: Product1 id= ctl00_cphMain_rPdctG_ctl01_hTitle, Product2 id=ctl00_cphMain_rPdctG_ctl02_hTitle . like this

Comment: I have updated question without for loop.. please have a look ..

Answer (score 0):

Here you add the product id in `<a>`

```
     $i=1;
     foreach ($posts as $posts) {
     $i=str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
     $str = $posts[1][0];
     preg_match('/<a id="ctl'.$i.'_cphMain_rPdctG_.*" href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>/m',$str,$match);
     print_r($match) . "\n"; 
     print($match[2]) . "\n";
     $i++;
}
```

Here `$posts['id']` is product id which you want. Or you add general by using like `$i=0;`, then inside loop use `$i++`

Comment: its not working. it returning blank array.. can you please run this code in your computer.

Comment: here $posts['id'] you use your table column of PRODUCT ID

Comment: you can inspect this given web-page and see products grid view  sturcture

Comment: Gopal it returns blank array and undefined offset

Answer (score 0):

Finally got what I want,

Here is the trick,

```
<?php 

$html = file_get_contents("website url here ");

preg_match_all(
    '/<div class=\"pdct\-inf\">(.*?)<\/div>/s',
    $html,
    $posts    
);

for ($i=0; $i < count($posts[0]); $i++) { 
$str = $posts[1][$i];
preg_match('/<a id="ctl00_cphMain_rPdctG_ctl.*_hTitle" href="(.*)">(.*)<\/a>/m',$str,$match);
print_r($match[1]) . "\n"; 
print($match[2]) . "\n\n";
fputcsv($csvfileoutput, array($match[2],$match[1]));
} 
?>
```